# How to capture or store value of AppCompatSpinner as a string in a String variable?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-spinner, android-appcompat

I have an `AppCompatSpinner` with 3 entries in it. I want the entry chosen to be stored as a `String` so that I can save it in my database.

Here's the XML code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/randomId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:entries="@array/aList"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
            </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add an `onItemClickListener` to your Spinner that does what you want.

It might look something like this:

```
    appCompatSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            saveToDb(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        }
    });
```

As an alternative, you could implement OnItemClickListener in your class if you prefer.

That is done like so:

```
public class MySpinnerActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate {
        AppCompatSpinner appCompatSpinner = (AppCompatSpinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);
        appCompatSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        saveToDb(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString())
    }
}
```